# How to create validated form in angular material dialog

Tags: angular, forms, validation, dialog, angular-material

I have material dialog and want to implement form validation inside.
If I create the form like:

```
    <form [formGroup]="qmForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(qmForm)">
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Add new Qmanager</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">.....</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button mat-button type="button" mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!qmForm.valid" type="submit">Add</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

I get error - `not allowed to load local resource, and blank page`.

If I make it like:

```
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography" [formGroup]="qmForm">
   <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required  formControlName="name" name='name'>
        <mat-error *ngIf="name.invalid">
            <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
                Name is required.
            </div>
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>

</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!qmForm.valid" type="submit">Add</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

there is no validation and get error - `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined`

In `app.module.ts` I have imported the form module:

```
 import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

in app.components.ts - also:

    import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
export class...{

public qmForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder..)
  ngOnInit () {
this.qmForm = new FormGroup({
     name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(60)]),
     hostname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(60)])

    }, { updateOn: 'blur' });

);

createQM(qmForm) {
    if(this.qmForm.valid) {
      alert("test");
    window.electronIpcSend('addQM', qmForm);

    this.qmForm.reset();
    }
  }
```

If you can help me to understand what I am missing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

to get valid state of control try to use like this

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="qmForm.controls.name.hasError('minlength')">Min length must be 6</mat-error>
```

And as the example above use it to another controls

**EDIT: try to use with `?`**

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="qmForm?.controls?.name?.hasError('minlength')">Min length must be 6</mat-error>
```

Comment: hello,thanks for the reply.
now i get:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

Comment: Try to use solution in EDIT

Comment: i am missing something. cannot understand what :(  now it is giving error in the submit button:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined.[disabled]="!qmForm.valid"

it should work.. but there is no error for min length .. nothing. 
for me seems to not start some validation scripts behind also no css..

Comment: You make something wrong. Can you put your code to stack blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms that i can clear understand your problem

Comment: i removed the qmform.valid and now seems better, at least i see the input field prettier :) but..:
Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:

       
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });


this formGroup i added in the dialog
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography" [formGroup]="qmForm">

Comment: plz add you code to stackblitz to clear solution. Now i cant help you because i dont see your code

Comment: the whole problem is that i use form in modal.. i want to make the post form - send json data to electron with IPCrenderer and save this json to file, and append..
i am using electron angular boilerplate and started to write on top of it. but cannot find working example of submit form in angular material modal..

Comment: You must define you from in dialog component

Comment: this is the part with the modal: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-dzjsyy

can you tell me how and where to define :)

Comment: export class DialogContentQMDialog {
   here you must define your FormGroup with FormControlss
}

Comment: ahh .. i have done this in AppComponent, not in the dialog one. 
doing .. thank you !